# build failed in xcode after react-native init

Tags: xcode, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cfk1.jpg)

I did these steps successfully:

- install node.js and the version is 4.0
- brew install watchman
- brew install flow
- the version of OS X Yosemite is 10.10.5
- the version of Xcode is 6.4
- npm install -g react-native-cli
- react-native init HelloWorld

In the end, I run the HelloWorld.xcodeproj,and it build failed like the picture above.
can you help me to solve this problem, thx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're opening the HelloWorld project folder and not the Xcode project. If you're using a terminal do this:

```
cd HelloWorld/ios
open HelloWorld.xcodeproj
```

or navigate to the ios folder in your HelloWorld application in finder and double click on the xcode project to open it in the right directory.